# When $f(t)-f(t-\tau)$ is already known, how to determine $f(t)$?

Tags: signal-processing, deconvolution

As an example, we want to measure $f(t)$, but it's hard to get it directly. What we can do is to measure $f(t)-f(t-\tau)$. How to use the information we have to find $f(t)$?

The only method I know is, when $\tau$ is small enough, $$f(t)-f(t-\tau) \approx \tau f'(t)$$ then integrate it. But I still feel this is not good enough.

**Motivation**

We need to measure the instant frequency of a tuneable laser source (or the instant phase $\phi(t))$, and through swept-wavelength interferometer we get the beat signal $\cos(\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau))$, where $\tau$ is the delay of two arms, so I'm struggling with dealing this issue. If any solutions here, please feel welcome to show your wisdom.

Comment: Solutions will be wildly non-unique - you can add any arbitrary $\tau$ periodic signal to a solution and still be a solution. Are there any other conditions you can add, like maybe a bandwidth limit?

Comment: For the case of constant frequency of the laser $A\cos[\phi(t)-\phi(t-\tau)] = A\cos\left(2\pi f_lt - 2\pi f_l t + 2\pi f_l \tau\right) = A \cos\left(2\pi f_l \tau\right) = A \cos\left(2\pi \left[f_l \tau + k\right]\right)$ .  In that case, if you know $A$ and $\tau$, a countable number of solutions for $f_l$ should be easy enough to determine.

Comment: It's a wavelength-swept laser actually, which means φ(t) = 2π(v0t+0.5*γ*t^2)+φ0

Answer (score 1):

The [transfer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) of the measurement device is

$$ H_M (s) = 1 - e^{- \tau s} $$

Note that if the delay $\tau$ is "sufficiently small", then $H_M (s) \approx \tau s$, which is a scaled differentiator.

One would like to find a "compensator" that undoes the measurement.  This compensator could have the following transfer function

$$ H_C (s) = \frac{1}{H_M (s)} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{- \tau s}} $$

Again, note that if the delay $\tau$ is "sufficiently small", then $H_C (s) \approx \frac{1}{\tau s}$, which is a scaled integrator.

The aforementioned compensator's could be implemented by the following

$$ y (t) - y (t - \tau) = u (t) $$

where $u$ is the compensator's input and $y$ is the compensator's output. Do you have access to a [delay line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_delay_line)? How accurate is your measurement of $\tau$?

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring answer. Here in the background τ is a constant. Now I get the the same idea as yours. Just do FFT to both sides of formula: F(y(t)-y(t-τ)) = F(u(t)), where F stands for Fourier Transform. Then we get Y(w)(1-exp(-jwτ)) = U(w), then Y(w) = U(w)/(1-exp(-jwτ)). In theory, y(t) will be solved just by doing inverse FFT of U(w)/(1-exp(-jwτ)). But I failed. I guess it would be the result that due to the existence of 1-exp(-jwτ) item, ifft can't be calculate. Would you help me solve this problem or offer other advice?

Comment: Note that the FFT is for finite discrete-time signals, i.e., finite sequences.  We are dealing with continuous-time signals, right? Also, note that the FFT is a fast algorithm for the DFT